# How two merge multiple list (with different datatypes) in c#?

Tags: c#

I have three lists with different data types and I want to merge them and create one single list. How can I do that? I am able to use `.Zip` for two lists but I am not sure how can I merge three lists?

Code:

```
var tagIdList = new List<int> {1,2,3}();
var tagSelectionList = new List<bool> {true, false, true}();
var tagList = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"}();

//Working for two lists
var tagIdAndSelectionList = tagIdList.Zip(tagSelectionList, (tagId, isTagSelected) => new { tagId, isTagSelected }).ToList();
```

Actual Result:

```
{tagId = 1, isTagSelected = true}
{tagId = 2, isTagSelected = false}
{tagId = 3, isTagSelected = true}
```

Expected Result of three list:

```
{tagId = 1, isTagSelected = true, tagName = "a"}
{tagId = 2, isTagSelected = false, tagName = "b"}
{tagId = 3, isTagSelected = true, tagName = "c"}
```

Comment: I think a simple for loop is enough

Comment: @Eser How am I going to loop through these different lists? I want one combine result which contains int, bool & string data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Linq

```
            List<int> tagIdList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
            List<bool> tagSelectionList = new List<bool>() { true, false, true };
            List<string> tagList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

            var results = tagIdList.Select((x, i) => new { tagId = x, isTagSelected = tagSelectionList[i], tagName = tagList[i] }).ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you

Comment: Note that this can fail if the lists are not of equal lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this obviously you have to do multiple zips...

```
var tagIdAndSelectionList = tagIdList.Zip(tagSelectionList,(tagId, isTagSelected) => new { tagId, isTagSelected }).ToList().Zip(tagList,(a,tagName)=> new {a.tagId,a.isTagSelected,tagName}).ToList();
```